# Identify anime series about detective agency ran by a guy and two women

Tags: story-identification, anime, detective

The three characters were adults running a struggling detective agency. They were in love with each other but hesitant to do anything about it. The community around them supported their love and were impatient for them to get on with it. Plot mostly revolved around running the agency rather than the love story that simmered on the back burner.

Not recent. Around 3-8 years ago.

Comment: Any science fiction or fantasy elements?

Comment: @DavidW I do remember a giant squid and a giant octopus monster fight taking place on a bridge in one of the later episodes.

Comment: Could you describe the appearance of the two women?

Comment: What I remember most is they didn't look like kids the way so many do in these anime. They weren't ridiculously endowed either. Just attractive.

Comment: What colour was their hair?

Comment: @LogicDictates if only my memory worked that way. Already came up empty doing a google image search.

Comment: The premise of detective agency run by a man and a woman barely reminds me of City Hunter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is ***[Futakoi Alternative](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0988816/)*** (2005).

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/FutakoiAlternative):

> *Futakoi Alternative* is a very loosely done Spinoff of the original *Futakoi*, which uses the original character designs and concept of twins and virtually nothing else. **The male protagonist is Futaba Rentarou, a 21-year-old Private Detective who spends most of his time waiting for a case. He's accompanied by his twin assistants 15-year-old Shirogane Sara and Shirogane Sojyu, whose mutual affection for him is completely open to a threesome.**
>
> Genre Shift occurs almost by the episode throughout this show. One more serious example takes Rentarou from trying to resolve conflicted feelings of romance and responsibility **to racing a bio-hybrid squid down a highway on a friend's bike in two adjacent episodes.** The show does have an overarching plot, dealing with a mutual (and surprisingly non-rival) sibling love triangle.

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/126/Futakoi_Alternative):

> **The Futaba Detective Agency, being run by Rentarou,** who has taken over the family business, after his father's death 3 weeks ago. Along w/ Sara & Souju, his live-in identical twin assistants. He ends up running afoul of the local Yakuza.

The show is about a detective agency run by a guy named Rentarou, along with his with two female assistants, twin sisters, Sara and Souju. There's also a talking, flying, bipedal squid called [Ikafire](https://myanimelist.net/character/16323/Ikafire), which serves as an antagonist in a few episodes, and a gigantic tentacled creature shows up to cause mayhem in the final episode.

[This review](http://phoenix512anime.blogspot.com/2005/09/futakoi-alternative-10.html) of episode 10 talks about the squid a little bit.

> The squid is actually the one who started the fires a couple of years back. It starts shooting fireballs at Rentarou and starts to choke him. One of the cops shoots of the tentacle that the squid was choking Rentarou with and escapes. Rentarou considers leaving Japan while Soujyu waits for him to find her on the river-side. He goes back home to see Sugisaku and the others threw him a party for the two year anniversary of the agency. They ask Rentarou where Soujyu was. Suddenly, he remembers that he was supposed to search for her. The old lady at the party snaps some sense into Rentarou which he begins to search for Soujyu. He searches for her during the night but with no success and ends up getting into an accident on the moped. He continues to search for her with his injuries even when the sun came up. Rentarou finds her on the river side and she goes into the river. He embraces Soujyu in the river and rests for the remainier of the day. The squid returns to set the city on fire during the night and Rentarou decides to fight against the squid.